# Minimal Circuit Decomposition for a 3 qubit gate

Tags: unitarity

I have this unitary matrix and i need to find the decomposition with the small number of c-not.
I tried to use Quantum Shannon Decomposition but the simple form of the matrix make me think that there is a better decomposition

[image: Matrix]

Comment: BQSkit may yield similar or better results - something to try out.

Answer (score 7):

The automatic method in cirq gets it down to 12:

```
import cirq
import numpy as np
ops = cirq.three_qubit_matrix_to_operations(
    cirq.LineQubit(0),
    cirq.LineQubit(1),
    cirq.LineQubit(2),
    np.array([
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ]),
)
print(cirq.Circuit(ops).to_text_diagram(transpose=True, use_unicode_characters=False))
```

It uses some CZs and some CNOTs but those are easily changed into each other.

```
0            1                  2
|            |                  |
Ry(0.25pi)   PhX(-0.583)^0.5    |
|            |                  |
|            @------------------@
|            |                  |
|            PhX(-0.583)^0.5    PhX(-0.75)
|            |                  |
|            Z^(-5/12)          |
|            |                  |
@------------@                  |
|            |                  |
Ry(-0.25pi)  |                  |
|            |                  |
@-------------------------------@
|            |                  |
Ry(0.25pi)   |                  PhX(-0.963)^0.712
|            |                  |
@------------@                  |
|            |                  |
Ry(-0.25pi)  PhX(0.703)^0.388   |
|            |                  |
Rz(-0.25pi)  @------------------@
|            |                  |
|            PhX(0.932)^0.427   PhX(0.892)^0.24
|            |                  |
|            @------------------@
|            |                  |
|            PhX(0.703)^0.388   PhX(-0.253)^0.712
|            |                  |
|            Z^-0.195           Z^0.811
|            |                  |
X------------@                  |
|            |                  |
Rz(-0.083pi) |                  |
|            |                  |
X-------------------------------@
|            |                  |
Rz(-0.583pi) |                  |
|            |                  |
X------------@                  |
|            |                  |
Rz(0.25pi)   PhX(0.935)^0.388   |
|            |                  |
X-------------------------------@
|            |                  |
|            |                  PhX(-0.868)^0.288
|            |                  |
|            @------------------@
|            |                  |
|            PhX(-0.294)^0.427  PhX(-0.723)^0.24
|            |                  |
|            @------------------@
|            |                  |
|            PhX(-0.0654)^0.612 PhX(-0.578)^0.712
|            |                  |
|            Z^-0.814           Z^0.198
|            |                  |
```

If you only use classical operations, I think it requires more than CNOTs. I think it needs at least three Toffolis.

Answer (score 1):

If it suffices to have a high-fidelity approximation, you can use Qiskit's [Approximate Quantum Compiler](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/synthesis_aqc.html). Using this method, I got this decomposition which uses 9 CNOTs only and has a gate fidelity $> 0.999999999$.

[image]

And here is the circuit in OpenQasm:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[3];
u(2.3561895,2.7463326e-06,-1.5707699) q[0];
u(1.5576622,-0.78531077,1.5576213) q[1];
u(3.1415867,-2.5716362,-1.1092422) q[2];
cx q[2],q[1];
u(1.5839314,-0.01313166,2.3562805) q[1];
u(2.3318564e-05,0.92545391,-pi) q[2];
cx q[2],q[0];
u(1.5708005,2.3561906,-1.5707922) q[0];
cx q[1],q[0];
u(1.5707911,-5.1910088e-06,0.78537627) q[0];
u(1.5445421,-0.78505374,0) q[1];
u(6.4580157e-07,-2.6046094,0) q[2];
cx q[2],q[1];
u(1.5445416,0.026227559,-0.78505262) q[1];
u(1.570798,-2.5261149,0) q[2];
cx q[2],q[0];
u(0.78540632,3.1415487,6.2187325e-05) q[0];
cx q[1],q[0];
u(2.3561864,-3.1415688,-3.1415589) q[0];
u(1.5708042,-pi,-pi) q[1];
u(pi/3,2.1862712,0) q[2];
cx q[2],q[1];
u(2.3036819,-pi/2,-pi/2) q[1];
u(0.78539973,2.6396889e-06,-pi) q[2];
cx q[2],q[0];
u(1.5707977,pi,2.3562036) q[0];
cx q[1],q[0];
u(pi/2,-pi,-5.4768189e-06) q[0];
u(1.5707942,2.3562523,-pi) q[1];
u(1.5707951,1.993468e-05,0) q[2];
```

This method is described in the paper "[Best Approximate Quantum Compiling Problems](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2106.05649)" by Madden and Simonetto.